# Live streaming from FFMPEG: output a window m3u8 and also an all-segments m3u8

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I've been experimenting with using FFMPEG to take an incoming RTMP stream, transcode into a selection of bitrates, and output it as HLS. It works.

I wanted to store the live stream as a VOD. And found by adding the `-hls_list_size 0` flag, sure enough, all segment are in the .m3u8. Making it super easy to turn into a VOD afterwards. So far, so good.

*But* the obvious consequence of using `-hls_list_size 0` is that now the m3u8 is huge during the live stream. That's fine for a VOD where it is only requested once, but less good during a live stream where it is requested over and over.

So ... my question: without re-transcoding, can FFMPEG output *both* an all-segments all.m3u8 (to keep internally for making a VOD afterwards, ie using `-hls_list_size 0`) **and** *also* output a sliding-window style latest.m3u8 (of only the last X segments, ie using `-hls_list_size 3`)?

That way, viewers of the live stream could be served that little latest.m3u8, as a tiny file, with only the last few segments in. And after the event ends, I'd ditch that little latest.m3u8 and only keep the all.m3u8 to make a VOD version of the stream?

Thanks!

Comment: Use the tee muxer: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#tee-1

Comment: @Gyan Ah ... interesting. I didn't know about that. That may work. I'll see if I can figure out the command

Comment: Hi @coder_uk, Could you please help me to achieve same if it worked for you?

Answer (score 3):

Here is my two cents. As @Gyan suggested in comments above I made use of tee command. This takes input single time and performance of my system remains almost same if I would do only Live. Only drawback is it creates duplicate copy of that many segments which are being used in HLS segments for live.

```bash
ffmpeg -y \
  -hide_banner \
  -i $input_url \
  -preset veryfast -g 48 -sc_threshold 0 \
  -map 0:1 -map 0:2 -map 0:1 -map 0:2 -map 0:1 -map 0:2 \
  -filter:v:1 "scale=-2:360" -c:v:1 libx264 -b:v:1 365k \
  -filter:v:2 "scale=-2:480" -c:v:2 libx264 -b:v:2 1600k  \
  -c:v:4 copy \
  -f hls -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 10 \
  -var_stream_map "v:0,a:0 v:1,a:1 v:2,a:2" \
  -hls_segment_filename "$stream_key-v%v/%d.ts" \
  -f hls -f tee \
  "[var_stream_map=\'v:0,a:0 v:1,a:1 v:2,a:2 \': \
  master_pl_name=\'master-live.m3u8\': \
  hls_flags=delete_segments: \
  hls_list_size=60]$master-live%v/live.m3u8| \
   [var_stream_map=\'v:0,a:0 v:1,a:1 v:2,a:2\': \
   master_pl_name=\'master-record.m3u8\': \
   hls_playlist_type=vod]$master-record%v/record.m3u8"
```